# Outline of notebook sections

Tags: notebooks, palettes

I've been looking for a simple outliner for Mathematica notebooks and found Yuri E. Kandrashkin Sidebar'TOC, but decided I need something simpler and dynamic.

Has anyone tried making a dynamic outliner before?

Comment: Here on SE, only questions are allowed.  This isn't really a question, so it doesn't fit.  I suggest you re-phrase it as a question, and post your own answer to it.  It's a common way to share such ideas here.

Comment: This could probably help : https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/NotebookOutlineMenu , in particular the "Applications" section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I've came up with so far:

```
Outline[] := 
 CreatePalette[
  Dynamic[Refresh[
    Column@Cases[
      NotebookRead /@ 
       Cells[SelectedNotebook[], 
        CellStyle -> {"Section", "Subsection", "Subsubsection", 
          "Subsubsubsection"}], 
      Cell[name_, 
        style : "Section" | "Subsection" | "Subsubsection" | 
          "Subsubsubsection", ___, CellID -> id_, ___] :> 
       Button[StringRepeat["#", 
          Ceiling[(StringLength[style]/ 3)] - 2] <> " " <> name , (
         NotebookFind[SelectedNotebook[], id, All, CellID];
         SelectionMove[SelectedNotebook[], All, CellGroup];
         FrontEndTokenExecute["OpenCloseGroup"];
         ), Appearance -> "Frameless"]], UpdateInterval -> 1]], 
  WindowSize -> {Fit, 550}, WindowFloating -> True, Saveable -> False,
   WindowTitle -> (WindowTitle /. 
     AbsoluteOptions[SelectedNotebook[]])]
```

and here is how it looks in action (the section names are clickable):
[image: Outline]

I invite everyone who sees this as a useful little thing, to play with it/make it prettier/more useful or just accept it as a small community contribution.

Comment: I would like to have your stilesheet if possible, or is this one of the default ones (it doesn't seem like it)?

Comment: Hi! I'm happy to [share](https://github.com/masteranza/MathematicaAnki/blob/master/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/Science.nb) it with you. Please note that it uses latex fonts, which are also written [in the repository](https://github.com/masteranza/MathematicaAnki/tree/master/Mathematica) in .otf format

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out on first chance I get.

Comment: The repository has since moved to [Science Notebooks](https://github.com/masteranza/ScienceNotebooks)